# Access denied Site Pages Office365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have just created a fresh office365 developer trial account. I am trying to upload webpart pages (.aspx which i created on my local sp2013) to site pages library but i am getting an access denied error when i try to upload them to Office365. to be more specific I am not able to upload only .aspx pages rest are uploaded Have i missed anything ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be, you have used farm solution code(Visual webpart) in the aspx page. The form solution is not supported in O365. Try to use Visual Webpart(sandbox) for developing the custom code. Then try it. It'll work.